# Is there a way to submit, update, or remove a photo in Google image search?

Tags: google-image-search

If I see a bad photo in the Google Image search result and want to remove it, or update it, how do I go about doing that?

I think it might be easier if Google image search got that photo from Twitter or Facebook's profile photo, so I can update my profile photo there and Google will fetch it.  But I updated my photo on Twitter, and Google image search doesn't show the new one -- maybe requiring 1 or 2 days to update.  Otherwise, how can we remove or update it in the Google image search result?

I sometimes feel like we might be in the age of judging a person in a few seconds, sometimes just by looking at a photo of a person online (so that's why many people may post a smiling photo).

It might matter less usually, but what if an employer uses the person's name to search online when you apply for a job?  The hiring manager might want to hire you, but when the director or the VP saw your photo online, he might say otherwise or express a concern if it is not a good photo. (or even if it is just a photo of you holding a beer glass, looking cool, while you are applying for a job in a serious office environment).

Comment: You need to get the image removed on the source site.

Answer (score 3):

From [Remove an image from Google - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4628134?hl=en)

> If you want to delete an (sic) photo from Google’s search results, you’ll
> usually need to work with the person who owns the site that has the
> image.
>
> ### How to remove an image

Note: Go to the above referred help article to see the detailed steps of each list item:

> - Remove an image from someone else’s site
> - Remove a deleted image from search results
> - Remove an image from your own site
> - Remove images from other Google products
>
> ### Why Google doesn’t remove most images
>
> Most images that show up in Google’s search results are from websites
> that aren’t owned by Google.
> Since we aren’t the owners of these sites, we can’t remove the images
> from the web.
>
> Even if we delete the image from Google’s search results, the image
> still exists and can be found on other search engines, or if people
> visit the URL directly.
>
> This is why your best option is to [contact the site's webmaster](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9109) who
> can remove the page entirely.