# Made my Instagram account private, still all the pictures show up on Google Search

Tags: images, instagram, google-image-search

When googling my name all my (now private) Instagram pictures shown up, linked to `www.pictaram.com/user/xxxx` addresses.

Is there any way to stop pictaram showing my pictures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to submit, update, or remove a photo in Google image search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87970/is-there-a-way-to-submit-update-or-remove-a-photo-in-google-image-search)

Comment: There's also a help article from Instagram on that topic: https://help.instagram.com/147542625391305